# OneDrive client status/health check

Tags: onedrive

I would like to programmatically validate that the OneDrive (for Business) client is successfully connected and syncing (SDK, file, event log, registry, etc.) on our Windows 10 desktops.

I have seen the [OneDriveLib](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2017/06/06/powershell-cmdlet-to-check-onedrive-for-business-or-onedrive-personal-status/) project, which claims to offer this through PowerShell, although it’s not working for me because of the [known bug](https://github.com/rodneyviana/ODSyncService/issues/3) when Files On-Demand is enabled.

We’re looking to implement OneDrive as the default save location for our 5000+ users. When it works, it works great, but how can we know it’s working for all our users? There’s a good possibility that some of the OneDrive clients will break at over time, so any locally saved data will not be synced. At best it will mean that the data will not roam with the user, but worst case scenario would be a machine goes pop with months/years of unrecoverable un-synced data.

Comment: How did you get on with this? Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

there are some local data files here, but i've yet to decipher their meaning:

```
$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive\logs\Business1\DeviceHealth.json |
```

and

```
$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive\logs\Business1\DeviceHealthSummaryConfiguration.ini
```